# Diameters of vessels metastases spread through

Tags: cancer, tumors, cells

As I know, one of the way tumor may metastasis is, forced by hypoxia, creating new vessels near it, connecting them to the main circulatory system and then spread cells through the blood.

If understand that correctly, can you please answer, is there information about the “metastatic” vessels diameter distribution?

I mean, what is the diameter of the vessels that tumor creates near it? Maybe capillaries(<8um)? Can cancer cells flow in aorta, for example? Which is the average vessels diameter metastases “prefer” to spread in?

Comment: Once a cell is in the circulation, how would it *not* flow through the aorta? It also seems like you are confusing angiogenesis with metastasis.

Comment: @BryanKrause I have such a bad knowledges in biology, so any help will be very useful. But, as far as I know (and as I mentioned in my question), capillaries diameter is tiny, and sometimes equals erythrocyte size. As I know cancer cell, that is bigger and less flexible can just stuck in capillary

Answer (score 2):

Studies with [high resolution intravital microscopy](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/31615867) have shown that cancer cells in circulation can deform and squeeze through vessels [as small as capillaries](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/29176592), which are usually 5-10 µm in diameter. [A large number of factors](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/26791720) contribute to whether a circulating tumor cell actually forms a metastatic tumor, including characteristics of the tumor cell, properties of the metastatic site, and conditions in circulation.

[Blood vessels within tumors are abnormal](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15637262) in many ways, and therefore size is only one of many factors to consider. Others include structure/leakiness of the blood vessel as well as the presence of supporting cell types like pericytes and immune cells.

Comment: Thank You, for feedback. Can I get that articles for free?

Comment: The articles that are deposited in PMC are free.